# Laravel observer add delay

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How can I add delay to laravel observer before it execute function?

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
public function created(School $school)
{
    $addTime = Carbon::parse($school->created_at)
      ->addSeconds(6);

    if(Carbon::now() = $addTime) {
        $manager = School::where('id', $school->id)->with('manager')->first();
        $user = User::where('id', $school->manager->id)->first();
        Mail::to($user->email)->locale('id')->queue(new SchoolGenerated($school, $user));
    }
}
```

Logic

I have such function in my controller

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $school = new School;
  //.....
  if($school->save()){
    //save manager.....
  }
}
```

As you see I assign manager to school after school data been saved therefore if I run my observe immediately It won't find my user (manager) so I need to put delay into my observer till manager data stored as well.

**How can I add delay to my observer?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

As there was no way for me to get school data after manager being created so I've changed my observe to rule on manager creation instead of school creation that way I can get manager data and based on manager data get school data. So I just basically rotate the logic 180˚ and got my desire result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sleep(int $seconds )` function in php, try this:

```
public function created(School $school) 
{
     // add delay
     $seconds = 10;

     sleep($seconds);

     $manager = School::where('id', $school->id)->with('manager')->first();
     $user = User::where('id', $school->manager->id)->first();
     Mail::to($user->email)->locale('id')->queue(new SchoolGenerated($school, $user));
}
```

}

Comment: still can't get manager data, i also changed my controller to make sure manager data are returning along with school data but it didn't make any changes to observe issue